# Предназначение логических операторов

Tags: java, python

Я знаю как с битами работать, типа сдвиги, операторы `|, &, ^`. В просторах интернета пишут, что они используются для низкоуровневых задач, в технике и тд.

Я обычно использую обычные операторы типа `||, &&` или же `and, or` и тд. и без них никак, то есть их предназначения понятны. Но вот предназначение логических побитовых операторов мне не совсем понятен.

Зачем мне они нужны, в каких случаях они мне пригодятся, рядовому программисту)?

Comment: Для битовых масок, например

Comment: and, or, not -- это логические операторы. |, &, ^ -- могут быть побитовыми операторами. Для каких именно операторов вы примеры ищите?

Comment: для них - |, &, ^, побитовых.

Answer (score 1):

Побитовые операции мало стоят, с точки зрения вычислений.
При их помощи можно быстро определить, является ли число степенью двойки или чётное ли оно.
Также они активно применяются в шифровании.
https://pas1.ru/bitarithmetic